# Self-summed numbers

Tags: code-golf, integer-partitions

## Convert a number to a sum of digits

**Not any sum:** we need the **shortest** sum
**Not any digits:** you can use only **digits of the number**

***Example***
You will be given as **input** an integer `n>0`

Let's say `n=27`. You have to express `27` as a **sum**, using **only the digits** `[2,7]`, in the **shortest** way possible. **You don't have to use all the digits of the given number!**

So `27=2+2+2+7+7+7`. We then **take those digits and count them**: `[2,2,2,7,7,7]`.
Final answer for `n=27` is `6`

One more example for `n=195` in order to get the **shortest sum** we have to use the following digits:
`[5,5,5,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]` and the **answer** is `23`

## The challenge

Given an integer `n>0`, output the **minimum number of digits** (contained in the number) that **sum up to this number**

## Test Cases

`Input->Output`

```
1->1  
2->1  
10->10  
58->8  
874->110  
1259->142  
12347->1765  
123456->20576  
3456789->384088
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Are there any numbers that cannot sum to themselves/will they be input?

Comment: @Stephen They all can!

Comment: @Stephen Because every number can be expressed as d_0 + 10*d_1 + 100* d_2, etc...

Comment: Can we take the input as string, char-array or integer-array?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen String is ok. char-array or integer-array are not.

Comment: How did you pick `[5,5,5,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]` over `[5,1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]`, is either correct?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yes, they are both correct. We are only interested in the minimum number of digits.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
Lḟo=⁰ΣṁΠḣ∞d⁰
```

Handles two-digit numbers pretty fast.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@fhjvn5to8aN5xb/HBn47kFD3csftQxLwUo8P//f1MLAA)

### Explanation

```
Lḟo=⁰ΣṁΠḣ∞d⁰  Input is n, say n = 13.
          d⁰  Digits of n: [1,3]
         ∞    Repeat infinitely: [[1,3],[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]...
        ḣ     Prefixes: [[],[[1,3]],[[1,3],[1,3]],[[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]],...
      ṁ       Map and concatenate
       Π      Cartesian product: [[],[1],[3],[1,1],[3,1],[1,3],[3,3],[1,1,1],[3,1,1],...
 ḟo           Find the first element
     Σ        whose sum
   =⁰         equals n: [3,3,3,3,1]
L             Return its length: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>168</s> <s>155</s> 144 bytes

It isn't the *shortest* it could be, but it's best-first and not *real* bad, runtime wise.

```
n=input()
g=sorted(set(n)-{0})[::-1]
def h(k):
 if k<0:return
 if`k`in g:return 1
 for d in g:
  f=h(k-int(d))
  if f:return 1+f
print h(int(n))
```

<s>The `filter(None...` is to remove 0 as a digit, which I learned I could do while making this.</s>

The biggest problem is python stack frames, which realistically don't allow me to run this on the largest inputs. So, it is not a valid solution, really, I played around with increasing the recursion limit which just led to seg-faults. This has to either be done with a loop and a stack or with a lot more cleverness to work in python.

edit: Thanks to caird and Chas Brown for 13 bytes!

Comment: You can use `input` and require the input to be surrounded with quotes.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to fail due to physical limitations, so long as it succeeds in theory, which this does.

Comment: Save 9 bytes by replacing `filter(None,sorted(map(int,set(n)))[::-1])` with `sorted(set(map(int,n))-{0})[::-1]` (although the `None` thing is pretty nice to know about).

Comment: @ChasBrown In most cases you can use `filter(len,...)` for lists and strings and `filter(abs,...)` for integers and floats.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
lef!-TsM`Q./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyc1TVE3pNg3IVBP//9/I3MA)

Unfortunately it memory errors on inputs as large as `58`.

#### Explanation

```
lef!-TsM`Q./
          ./    All lists of integers that sum to [the input]
  f             Filter for:
    -TsM`Q           Remove all occurrences of the digits in the input
   !                 Check if falsey (i.e. an empty list)
le              Length of the last occurrence, which is the shortest because all the
                filtered partitions share the same digit pool
```

Comment: would you mind adding an explanation?

Comment: @Jonah Explanation added.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting that Pyth has a primitive that essentially solves the problem in `./`

Comment: 12-byte alternative: `lef<.{TjQ;./` (filter - proper subset - of input's digits)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
(t=1;While[(s=IntegerPartitions[x=#,t,IntegerDigits@x])=={},t++];Tr[1^#&@@s])&
```

finds last test case in 5 sec

Comment: A little bit shorter: `Length@IntegerPartitions[#, All, Sort@DeleteCases[0]@IntegerDigits@#,     1][[1]] &`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 78 bytes

```r
function(n){while(all(F-n)){F=outer(F,n%/%10^(0:nchar(n))%%10,"+")
T=T+1}
T-1}
```

[Try it online! (golfed version)](https://tio.run/##FYzRCoMgFEDf/QophHupmDYGbeBrX@DzQERJKAVLxoi@3bmX83A4nFScLC4Hc/gYIOD5WfxqQa8rzENAPGcZ82ETzH1gNyb4G/grmEWnGiOrom@6BomSqhMXUYO4ioPHhMTBeP9zeiJpqQMxcqQtNTrvdqeb3WL60sNvtv7LDw)

Pure brute force algorithm, so it doesn't actually solve all the test cases, and I think it tried to allocate 40,000 GB for the last test case...

`T` in R defaults to `1` so we get an off-by-one error which we correct at the return step, but we also get `F` which defaults to `0` which pays off.

ungolfed explanation:

```r
function(n){
 d <- n%/%10^(0:nchar(n))%%10   # digit list with a 0 appended at end
 d <- unique(d[d>0])            # filter zeros (not technically necessary)
                                # and get unique digits
 x <- 0                         # storage for sums
 i <- 0                         # counter for number of sums done
 while(!any(x==n)){             # until we find a combination
  x <- outer(x,d,"+")           # take all sums of x and d, store as x
  i <- i + 1}                   # increment counter
i}                              # return counter
```

[Try it online! (less golfy version)](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoQgEADQ@/zFBsJIQXYNpqM/EbsQjUtCTCRJRvTt5vXxQs7/KPPhN0HRN5OoVnXmh6aXeZlCQa0KAFMUv0eHPPJgvhoSGTgXvzr8THJhIir1TrTFwwVMDTdVXWmwZOvuAfvk/AI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

Pretty inefficient

```
VVo=⁰ΣMṖNṘ⁰d⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pyws3/ZR44Zzi30f7pzm93DnDCAnBYj///9vaAwA)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

```js
f=(n,l=0,a=n,[c,...b]=a)=>n?1/c?Math.min(!+c|+c>n?1/0:f(n-c,l+1,a),f(n,l,b)):1/0:l
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Takes input as a string.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `1/0`?

Comment: @Zacharý I want the shortest sum, i.e. the minimum number of digits. Attempts which lead to an invalid solution mustn't count, so to exclude them, they score Infinity, which doesn't affect the minimum.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it's recursive.

Comment: @Zacharý The `f=` at the beginning is a big clue, since you don't need it for nonrecursive lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
->n{w,s=n.digits,0;s+=1while !w.product(*[w]*s).find{|x|x.sum==n};s+1}
```

Very slow, try all the possible combinations increasing the size until we get to a solution.

Thanks Dennis for Ruby 2.4 on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vulyn2DZPLyUzPbOkWMfAuljb1rA8IzMnVUGxXK@gKD@lNLlEQyu6PFarWFMvLTMvpbqmoqZCr7g019Y2rxao3LD2f4FCWrShQSwXiDa1iP0PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
D;0ṗµḟ€0
ÇS€=µT
Çị1ĿL€Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/F2uDhzumHtj7cMf9R0xoDrsPtwUDa9tDWECDz4e5uwyP7fYACD3c2/f//39AAAA)

This is so inefficient, that it does not run for the test cases after the third one on TIO due to a time limit >_<

Any golfing tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 91 bytes

```hs
f n=[read[c]|c<-show n,c>'0']#n!!0
s#n|n>0,x:m<-(s#).(n-)=<<s=[1+minimum(x:m)]|1<3=[0|n==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRCsIgFADQ977iDoMpzXBEEMO7HxEfxDYm7d5iLurBf7fO61lCfkzrWusMjG6bwt1FX6LVeXl@gLs4tqb1gpvGHLLgwqPpvgNZLbNQZ8laobUZXX@ixIneJP@rfOntBZ0pjGh8pZAYEF5b4h2OMMP1Vn8) Example usage: `f 58` yields `8`. Quick for two-digit numbers, horrendously slow for larger inputs.

The function `f` converts the input number `n` into a list of digits while filtering out zeros. Then this list and `n` itself are handed to the `(#)` function, which returns a singleton list. `!!0` returns the element of this singleton list.

`(#)` uses singleton and empty lists as option type. Given an input of `n=58` and `s=[5,8]`, the idea is to subtract all digits in `s` from `n`, then recursively apply `(#)` and check which digit resulted in the minimum number of steps and return one plus this minimum as result. The first part is computed by `(s#).(n-)=<<s`, which is the same as `concat(map(s#)(map(n-)s))`. So in our example first `[58-5,58-8]` is computed, followed by `[[5,8]#53,[5,8]#50]` which results in `[[7],[7]]` or `[7,7]` after `concat`. The result is matched on the pattern `x:m` to make sure the list has at least one element (`minimum` fails otherwise), then the singleton list of 1 plus the minimum of the result is retuned. If `n` was smaller zero or the recursive call returned an empty list, we are in a failing branch of the search and an empty list is returned. If `n==0` the branch was succeeding and `[0]` is returned.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 101 bytes

```hs
f n=[d|d<-[9,8..1],show d!!0`elem`show n]#n!!0
s@(d:r)#n|n>=d,[x]<-s#(n-d)=[x+1]|1<3=r#n
s#n=[0|n==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LboMwEEX3/oqJ6CJRTGTeTsVU/Q9kKRQbgQKTCtM2kfh3aqCP3bln5s40pb2arpvnGggLPencL85cnk6B4ra5fYHe7cTFdKa/rJGUR84w@7rXz8PBo4leUPPirnLfenvy9QGL@zFQU5BHOHjErOcOi4kQhZr7siVA0Ddg4PtQNaa6QkkPoI/@zQwM3oeWRniCGoIwijO2rn2aoa0fUHYdjMaOUJXW2P/dkjQUDJYOYsBXCheCTQrHYtOJRJQbyix2/ncQhMnZxTjk8NNa3juTpQn/E0mKGIokSze1iEy6XiRjIaWavwE) A way more efficient approach, checks all test cases in under one second.

This time, the list of digits of the input is computed to be in descending order, which allows `(#)` to try to use the largest digit as often as possible, then the second largest, and so until a solution is found. The first solution found this way is also guaranteed to be the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>183</s> <s>176</s> <s>172</s> <s>166</s> 161 bytes

```python
def f(n,D=0,p=0,b=0):
	D=D or set(map(int,`n`))-{0}
	d=min(D);c=0;D=D-{d}
	q=[p+n/d,b][n%d>0]
	while c<min(D or{0}):q=b=f(n-c*d,D,p+c,b);c+=1
	return[q,b][q>b>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7LboMwEDzjr@BSxS5GNQQCIV1O/gsUKTUmCVKzMZSqqqJ@O1276mFnRvuYHfe9XO@Yr6sdzvGZo9SgpKMyoETDIg06vs/xx7Dw25vjIy7yhCch0of6YZGF24hci0MP6kCr6cNSd4LOJfhipTl2@GRbdWTR13V8H@L@NeyTI52LZgID9DPtn63U0iW9NGSVQMaieVg@Z@wm7zG1hjxCwgtH0biZYsQoN9BuJN0LduGZhzwo5bGsPdZVEVp5uf/jbVH9i3LnleeqDtN9Xe3KYptnYv0F)

Longer than the other Python answer, but performs all test cases combined plus `987654321` in under a second on TIO.

Takes advantage of the fact that if `d1<d2` are digits, then there need be at most `d2-1` `d1`'s in the sum (since `d2` instances of `d1` can be replaced with `d1` instances of `d2` for a shorter sum). Thus, sorting the digits in ascending order, there are "only" at most `9! = 362880` possible sums to consider; and a maximum recursion depth of `9` (regardless of the value of `n`).